# Getting Notified for Questions from other Users

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Should it be possible to get an inbox-notification from a question that another user has posted? For example I have found a question that was similar to an issue that I had, and instead of posting my own, I would like to be able to "follow" this question and get notified when someone answers or comments on it, instead of having to check on the question every day.

The way I think of it, there should be a button that lets you follow a question, much like the Favorited button. Then you will be notified when this question is:

- Updated
- Answered
- Commented On

You could even change the settings so you can only get notified for certain events: "Question was Answered".

These notifications could be shown in a different colour perhaps as opposed to the red of the normal ones, so you can differentiate it more easily.

What do you think of this?

Comment: So, it's favorite+, actions aren't only shown in the favorite-tab, but your inbox...